# How do I add a gradient to a UISegmentedControl

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to add a gradient to the unselected buttons in a UISegmentedControl... Ideally in swift.  Something like this (though I'm not necessarily interested in a gradient for the selected button):

[image: gradient example]
<sub>(source: [lescampeurs.org](http://charles.lescampeurs.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/uisegmentedcontrol.png))</sub>